# How to optimize SwiftUI previews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

Is There a way to optimize SwiftUI preview builds so it can be done faster ?
I have a very big project and each time I need to do a View preview it would take forever building the entire project

For example I don't want some pods to be compiled on build isa there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Found this, not sure if it is really making a difference but could be worth a try: https://daniel-reiling.medium.com/reducing-xcode-build-times-for-unit-tests-and-swiftui-preivew-builds-c689270d1879